# Running calculations on different percent amounts of data - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I'm brainstorming on ways to find trends over a dataset containing transaction amounts that spans a year.

I'd like to run an average of top 25% observations of data and bottom 75% observations of data and viceversa.

If the entire dataset contains 1000 observations, I'd like to run:

1. An average of the top 25% and then separately, an average of the bottom 75% and find the resulting average of this.
2. Inversely, top 75% average, then bottom 25%, then the average of the 2.

For the overall average I have: `avg(transaction_amount)`

I am aware that in order for the sectioning averages to be useful, I will have to order the data according to the date which I already have accounted for in my SQL code:

```
select avg(transaction_amount)
from example.table
order by transaction_date
```

I am now struggling to find a way to split the data between 25% and 75% based on the number of observations.

Thanks.

Comment: what DBMS? MSSQL has `PERCENT` support for the `SELECT` statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: DBMS is SSMS. If I'm understanding correctly, I'd have to run 2 queries, first with top 25% calculation, then second with 75% calculation.

Comment: SSMS is just a tool that works with several DBMS. Which DBMS are you using it for? Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yup, Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, isn't SSMS exclusively for SQL Server? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio

Comment: This is what I've always assumed in 4+ years working with SQL but it might technically be wrong to equate the two?

Comment: @jarlh: I actually don't know. On their website they say "SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is an integrated environment for managing any SQL infrastructure", but then they add "from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database" which doesn't sound like a broad range of DBMS :-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MSSQL, it's pretty trivial depending on exactly the output you're looking for.

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT
  *
FROM (
   SELECT 
     AVG(transaction_amount) as avg_amt
   FROM example.table
) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.avg_amt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PERCENT_RANK` in order to see which percentage block a row belongs to. Then use this to group your data:

```
with data as
(
  select t.*, percent_rank() over (order by transaction_amount) as pr
  from example.table t
)
select
  case when pr <= 0.75 then '0-75%' else '75-100%' end as percent,
  avg(transaction_amount) as avg,
  avg(avg(transaction_amount)) over () as avg_of_avg
from data
group by case when pr <= 0.75 then '0-75%' else '75-100%' end
union all
select
  case when pr <= 0.25 then '0-25%' else '25-100%' end as percent,
  avg(transaction_amount) as avg,
  avg(avg(transaction_amount)) over () as avg_of_avg
from data
case when pr <= 0.25 then '0-25%' else '25-100%' end;
```